# How to change an array value with a method call in Android when using Firebase and Android

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following method in Android (implemented in Java):

```
public  static void getInformationWhenInfoButtonIsPressed (FirebaseRatingCallback callback,float [] ratingValue,  String item) {
        
              DatabaseReference rootRef_Firebase;
              rootRef_Firebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_URL).getReference();
                rootRef_Firebase
                        .child(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_NODE_RATINGS_AGGREGATED)
                        .orderByChild(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_NAME)
                        .equalTo(item)
                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                int numberOfRatingsOverall = 0;
                                double tempScoreOverall =0;
                                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    float averageRatingOfCurrentDrink = 0;
                                    int numberOfRatingsCurrentDrink = 0;
        
                                    if (ds.child(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_AVERAGE_RATING).getValue(Float.class)!=null) {
                                        averageRatingOfCurrentDrink= ds.child(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_AVERAGE_RATING).getValue(Float.class);
                                    }
        
                                    if (ds.child(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_NUMBER_OF_RATINGS).getValue(Integer.class)!=null) {
                                        numberOfRatingsCurrentDrink = ds.child(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_NUMBER_OF_RATINGS).getValue(Integer.class);
                                        numberOfRatingsOverall=  numberOfRatingsOverall + numberOfRatingsCurrentDrink ;
                                    }
                                    tempScoreOverall = tempScoreOverall + numberOfRatingsCurrentDrink * averageRatingOfCurrentDrink;
        
        
                                }
        
                                ratingValue[0] = (float) (tempScoreOverall/numberOfRatingsOverall);
        
                            }
        
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                                throw error.toException();
                            }
                        });
        
        
        
        
        
                ratingValue[0] = (float) (Math.round(ratingValue[0] * 10.0) / 10.0);
        
            }
```

And within the same class I have the following interface:

```
public interface FirebaseRatingCallback {
    void onCallBackRating (boolean dataIsReadFromFirebase); }
```

The method should change the value of the reference data type array `ratingValue[0]`. Unfortunately Firebase Realtime database works asynchronously so I have to use a callback which I do using `FirebaseRatingCallback callback`. But I don't know how to do this using a `ValueEventListener` as I am doing in this example. I know how to do this with a `OnCompleteListener` because there you have the method `public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {` which I can't use when having a `ValueEventListener`.

So I tried to add the following but this does not work:

```
public  static void getInformationWhenInfoButtonIsPressed (FirebaseRatingCallback callback,float [] ratingValue,  String item) {
    
        DatabaseReference rootRef_Firebase;
        rootRef_Firebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_URL).getReference();
        rootRef_Firebase
                .child(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_NODE_RATINGS_AGGREGATED)
                .orderByChild(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_NAME)
                .equalTo(item)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        int numberOfRatingsOverall = 0;
                        double tempScoreOverall =0;
                        for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            float averageRatingOfCurrentDrink = 0;
                            int numberOfRatingsCurrentDrink = 0;
    
                            if (ds.child(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_AVERAGE_RATING).getValue(Float.class)!=null) {
                                averageRatingOfCurrentDrink= ds.child(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_AVERAGE_RATING).getValue(Float.class);
                            }
    
                            if (ds.child(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_NUMBER_OF_RATINGS).getValue(Integer.class)!=null) {
                                numberOfRatingsCurrentDrink = ds.child(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_NUMBER_OF_RATINGS).getValue(Integer.class);
                                numberOfRatingsOverall=  numberOfRatingsOverall + numberOfRatingsCurrentDrink ;
                            }
                            tempScoreOverall = tempScoreOverall + numberOfRatingsCurrentDrink * averageRatingOfCurrentDrink;
    
    
                        }
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            ratingValue[0] = (float) (tempScoreOverall/numberOfRatingsOverall);
                            callback.onCallBackRating(true);
                        }
    
    
    
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        throw error.toException();
                    }
                });
    
    
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Have you considered trying to use [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)? Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50035915/firebaseauth-authstatelistener-using-livedata-is-there-scope-for-improvement-in) will help.

Comment: @AlexMamo: Thanks Alex for your comment. Actually in this case I don't want to use LiveData. LiveData would drastically increase the communication with the database as it would always update whenever something changes. I just want to execute a query and after the query has returned something, the method `getInformationWhenInfoButtonIsPressed` should change the arrays or return something. I know that I have to use a callback but I don't know how to use this in this case

Comment: `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` is triggered precisely once. It isn't listening for real-time updates. So the LiveData object will be updated only once ;) There are no other future events.

Comment: @AlexMamo: Well LiveData gets updates whenever something changes in the Real time database. For my single app, the changes made by other clients might be irrelevant and using liveData would communicate with the database whenever something changes. This is why I would like to have a single query, that is only executed when it is needed. But I need a confirmation or something with a Callback. I know how to do this when writing into the database, but I don't know how to do this when reading something out of it. Do you have any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> I know how to do this when writing into the database, but I don't know how to do this when reading something out of it.

The simplest solution would be to call get() on a query object, and once the operation is complete, update the LiveData object. After that, simply observe the change in the UI.

From the documentation of [Query#get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#get()):

> Executes the query and returns the results as a QuerySnapshot.

So once the query is complete, there will be no other future events, even if the database changes. So there will be nothing that will affect your UI after the query is complete.

**Edit:**

> Is it not possible to do this without LiveData?

There are other methods to do that, but this is by far the simplest one. Callbacks are not recommended to be used anymore.

> When using LiveData I need a lot of code because I'd also need 2 additional classes (ViewModel and LiveData class).

What's wrong with that? That's programming. Regarding, a ViewModel that's the way the Android team recommends building the apps.

> not do something completely new with LiveData and ViewModel as this would also take too much time and increase the complexity because of the many classes.

It won't take much time. It will take a matter of minutes. As soon as you understand those concepts, you'll be a better Android developer. Don't be afraid to learn something new.

P.S. Java is still a great language, but for Android development, I recommend Kotlin. What you are trying to achieve can be written in Kotlin using a single line of code.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer. Is it not possible to do this without LiveData? When using LiveData I need a lot of code because I'd also need 2 additional classes (ViewModel and LiveData class). I'd strongly prefer not to use live data. Is there not a way to use a callback instead as you can do when writing something into the database? I just want to slightly change the code above and not do something completely new with LiveData and ViewModel as this would also take too much time and increase the complexity because of the many classes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alex. I tried to do this with LiveData and in the ViewModel class I would like to know if I can specify a query for a certain `item`? At the moment I just let the ViewModel query return all items by using the query in the ViewModel `private static final Query QUERY_RATINGS = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_URL).getReference().child(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_NODE_RATINGS_AGGREGATED).orderByChild(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_NAME);` Then in the `observe` method of the fragment I filter the returned datasnapshot accoring to `item`. This needs a lot of data

Comment: Yes, you can add to the LiveData object the results of a query or a single object. A LiveData is nothing else but a holder for object/objects. It's a type of data that can be observed. Is it clear now?

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. How can I add a `item` that should be used for the Firebase Query in the query defined in the ViewModel class? At the moment I just define a general query that returns all items of the database using `private static final Query QUERY_RATINGS = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_URL).getReference().child(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_NODE_RATINGS_AGGREGATED).orderByChild(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_NAME);` in the ViewModel class. How can I pass a current `item` to it such that I can query `.equalTo(item)`?

Comment: It sounds like your question started off about how to get async data and now you're just asking about how to work with a ViewModel and a LiveData. At this point, you should probably think about asking a new question that illustrates what you have tried and what's not working the way you expect.

Comment: Can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually for me this is a direct follow up question to your answer. In my question I query after a certain item using `.equalTo(item)` and I want to know how I can do that with LiveData (in Java) as you suggested. In the view model class I have the query `private static final Query QUERY_RATINGS = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_URL).getReference().child(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_NODE_RATINGS_AGGREGATED).orderByChild(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_NAME);` that does not contain the `.equalTo(item)`  part and I would like to know how to include that

Comment: Follow-up questions should be added separately. So please add a new question, and show us what you have tried, with its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Hey VanessaF. Can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually I am still trying to figure out how to use your suggested approach but still query only for 1 item directly in the query and not to return every item of the database and filter in the `observe` method of the fragment

Comment: If you only want a single item from a query, then you should consider using [limitToFirst()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#limitToFirst(int)) or [limitToLast(n)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#limitToLast(int)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alex. What I want are several entries that are `.orderByChild(FIREBASE_NAME)` and that are `.equalTo(item)`. So I would like to return all entries of the firebase database whose attribute `FIREBASE_NAME` is equal to `item`. In a normal query it is easy to specify that. But when using the ViewModel to define the query with LiveData, I don't know how to pass the `item` from the fragment to the ViewModel. So instead I just let the viewmodel return every item of the database and filter in the `observe` method of the fragment. This works, but it produces a lot of data

Comment: Simply pass, or inject (using Hilt) that instance right inside the ViewModel class constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this does not work as always no matching item is returned. I think this is because in the ViewModel I have to use a static varialble `static String item` and then I use the query `private static final Query QUERY_RATINGS = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_URL).getReference().child(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_NODE_RATINGS_AGGREGATED).orderByChild(DataBaseEntries.FIREBASE_NAME).equalTo(item);`